# Web API + MongoDB: list of arbitrary objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a .Net Core 2.0 Web API in which I'm using the MongoDB .net driver.

I have a class called `ListOfValues`:

```
public class ListOfValues
{
    public string ListName { get; set; }
    public List<object> MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

My controller's endpoint for saving is:

```
public class LovController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] ListOfValues lov)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        await ldbContext.GetCollection<ListOfValues>("ListOfValues").InsertOneAsync(lov);
        return CreatedAtAction("Create", new { Id = lov.Id });
    }
}
```

I'm posting this data:

```
{
    "listName": "test",
    "MetaData": [{
        "Name": "Text",
        "FieldType": "TextBox",
        "isActive": 1
    }]
}
```

For some reason, when I query the DB I see this value:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1421e644d7cb07a8d3c45d"),
    "ListName" : "test",
    "MetaData" : [ 
        {
            "_t" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
            "_v" : {
                "Name" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue",
                    "_v" : []
                },
                "FieldType" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue",
                    "_v" : []
                },
                "isActive" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue",
                    "_v" : []
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that if I use a list of a specified type such as class or struct it will work, but I need the list to be a dynamic object since I don't know which objects the client may send.

What do I need to do for the data saved in the DB to be readable?

Comment: Can you please add examples of your metadata classes in C#? Your issue is related to Newtonsoft.Json; it has nothing to do with MongoDB driver.

Comment: I don't have classes for the metadata property. It's supposed to be a dynamic JSON array that the client sends. I don't even have a reference to Newtonsoft.Json in my code so I don't know why it appears there.

Comment: Oh I see. So, you would like data in the DB to look the same as in the request, right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I cannot pull it back after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<string, object>` to represent data of unknown structure.

This works both with Newtonsoft.Json, which is the default serializer in ASP.NET Web API, and with BSON serializers of MongoDB.Driver.

Change the `ListOfValues` class as follows:

```
public class ListOfValues
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string ListName { get; set; }

    public List<Dictionary<string,object>> MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

The `Id` property is required in order to fetch data from the DB. With `JsonIgnore` attribute, it won't be present in the JSON returned/received by the controller.

**Tested with**:

- ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API
- Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3
- MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4
- MongoDB server 3.4 w/WiredTiger

Comment: It's so simple and obvious I don't know how I missed it. But, I've also found a very useful link in the MongoDB manual that covers a lot of interesting materials to know about working with the MongoDB C# driver - [Serialize Documents with the CSharp Driver](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver.html)

Comment: For me, using `Dictionary<string,object>` only avoided using "_t" and "_v" for the top-level values. For nested values, it still uses _t and _v. Any ideas?

Comment: @Meglio any luck making it work with nested values?

Comment: @hahaha unfortunately no

Comment: @Meglio if you are still interested for a solution, this helped me out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47515074/3522714